# Remove words in list that are present in other elements

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I am trying to remove elements in a list that are present within other elements

for example:

```
l = ['word1', 'word1 word2', 'word3 word2', 'word2', 'word4']
```

the output of the function should be:

```
['word3 word2', 'word1 word2', 'word4']
```

because '`word1`' and '`word2`' are present in index 1 and 2 of the original list respectively

This is the algorithm I've come up with. It solves this in ~O(n^2)

```
l = ['word1', 'word1 word2', 'word3 word2', 'word2', 'word4']

s = set(l)

for root_word in l:
    for item in (s-set([root_word])):
        if root_word in item:
            if root_word in s:
                s.remove(root_word)

print(s)
```

Does anyone know of a more optimal solution? Maybe one using python built-ins to speed things up

Comment: Is there's "word1 word2 word3" in the list, what would be the output?

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is not O(n^2), but O(m.n^2) where m is the maximum number of words in an element of your list. You can use a `frozenset` of words for each entry of your list and then use the `issubset` method to test each of them. This will improve the performance for cases where your elements have a lot of words, but the complexity won’t change.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['word1', 'word1 word2', 'word3 word2', 'word2', 'word4']
s = set(l)
x = [s.remove(root_word) for root_word in l for item in (s-set([root_word])) if root_word in item if root_word in s ]   
print(s)
```

I used  List Comprehension technique to execute take ~20micr0sec

Comment: 1. Low readability, 2. What is the complexity of this solution?

Comment: hello  , time complexity o(n*m) , i dont know much about time complexity in list comp , but compare with user's doubt it give some optimal solution , and thanks for reply and plz correct me if am wrong